# How to know which button is pressed in a list of views - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a `ResidentsView()` which contains a list of `ResidentCell()`, and every cell has its own button. This button adds a stripe to one's name. Currently, it only increases the top resident because I've given that as the default resident for testing. However, I want the stripes of the person to increase when the button beneath their name is pressed. How do I access which button is pressed out of the four cells so I know who's stripes I have to increase?

```
struct ResidentCell: View {

    @State var showStripeView: Bool = false


    var resident: Resident

    var body: some View {


        VStack {
            HStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(resident.name)
                        .font(.title)
                    Text(String(resident.year))
                        .font(.caption)
                }.padding(.leading)

                Spacer()

                Text("Streepjes: \(numberOfStripes(stripes: resident.stripes))")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    .foregroundColor(resident.stripes > 4 ? .red : .black)

            }

            Divider()
                .frame(width: 200)

            Button(action: {
                self.showStripeView.toggle()
                }) {
                Text("Add stripe")
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.green, width: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .cornerRadius(5)


                }
            .padding(.top, 5)
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .sheet(isPresented: $showStripeView) {
                AddStripeView(currentUser: Resident.testResidents[0])
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfStripes(stripes: Int) -> String {
        let count = stripes

        var stripeString = ""

        for _ in (1...count) {
            stripeString.append("I")
        }

        return stripeString
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to increase resident.stripes value when button click?

Comment: By "given that as the default resident for testing" do you mean Resident.testResidents[0]? You can have a @State integer that each button can assign an array index to, then pass that index into testResidents.